# When (and why) was Spider-Man called the most important hero of them all?

Tags: story-identification, spider-man, episode-identification, marvel

I read some comic recently in which Spider-Man and Wolverine are fighting Cable with Cyclops somehow involved too. They were on a cave and the daughter of Cable was involved. (I’m not familiar with Cable or X-Men post-Phoenix so that’s all the information I can give you.)

Anyway, at some point Cable makes some remark along the lines of Spider-Man being “the most important hero of them all” or something similar.

I don't remember exactly which comic this was, but I think it was part of Civil War, possibly a New Avengers comic.

Can you identify the comic issue? And most importantly, is that comment ever explained? And if so, where?

Answer (score 15):

The issue is [Avengers: X-Sanction](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/39772/avengers_x-sanction_2011_1) (pages 5 + 6).

It hinted to the fact that Spider-Man holds a great significance in the Marvel Universe.

[image: Avengers X-Sanction Page 5]

Comment: Yes!! That's it. Do you know if that's ever explained or expanded somewhere?

Comment: I don't believe it was ever explained I haven't read that many comics recently but I remembered this one..  I means it's implied that Spiderman's legacy will make him out to be the greatest hero... So this mean that in the future he is regarded as such, though I'm not sure there's any canon material connecting this to anything in particular

Comment: Of course Spider-Man’s the greatest hero of all! I’m just surprised anyone could doubt that.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I believe it's something of a standard bit of comic lore that J. Jonah Jameson disagrees with you.

Answer (score 6):

I remember the comment, but I don't remember the exact issue (I'll try and dig it out tonight if I have some time).

While the comment is never explicitly explained, I feel like the answer is really two-part.

1) Spider-Man is the last Avenger standing during a rescue mission.

> He baits Magick and Colossus into fighting each other, releasing the Phoenix Force from the both of them. Thanks to this, a number of Avengers are rescued and the Phoenix Force is left only in Cyclops.

2) Spider-Man became Hope's final teacher/mentor while in K'un-L'un. He teaches her the most important lesson that he's ever learned himself:

**With great power comes great responsibility.**

[image: Spidey and Hope]

This comes into play in the final act of the event as

> Hope understands that the sheer amount of power of the Phoenix Force is too much for *anyone* (or any five people for that matter). In the end, she mimics Scarlet Witch's powers and uses them to destroy the Phoenix Force completely.

Comment: Aaaaah! "I can also tell you this..." WHAT?! The suspense is killing me!

Comment: I also don't think she destroyed the Phoenix Force. I think she removed the ability of humans to access it. Since it is a cosmic force on par with Galactus, Eternity and Death, it should be more difficult to destroy than with the powers of a mutant, even one as badly written as the Scarlet Witch...

Comment: @Thaddeus, Yeah - I was a little unclear on that myself when I read it - but all of the synopses I could find (to verify my memories, of course) said that she had destroyed it.

Comment: Destroyed until the next writer at Marvel, reading back and seeing how the Phoenix Force fought Galactus to a standstill, decides whichever writer got rid of such a useful writing element was stupid, decides to bring it back. It will take ten years or less. I'd bet money on it.

Comment: What issue is this from?